# Xamarin Create rounded image using a Frame

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I want to create a rounded image, so I created this code:

```
<Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalOptions="Center"
    CornerRadius="100" IsClippedToBounds="True" HeightRequest="70" WidthRequest="70">
    <Image Source="User_Vreesie_Logo.png"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</Frame>
```

Now I hoped that I would get a rounded image with the size 70x70, but I get very long (width) frame with rounded corners and a tiny squared image in the middle. How can I fix this?

Comment: your frame is expanding to fill TWO grid cells because you have the ColumnSpan set to 2.

Comment: Yeah, but I need it to be 2 cells wide

Comment: Okay I created 2 Grids so I can put it on ColumnSpan 1, but now the Frame is a circle and the image is a tiny square in the circle? How can I fix that?

Comment: set Padding="0"

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Hi , have you referred Jason's suggestion to solve it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these:

1. Frame has default padding of 25.So,set `Padding="0"`
2. Give `HeightRequest`/ `WidthRequest` to the image as Image doesn't seems to automatically scale in Xamarin.
3. Set `Aspect="AspectFit"` in `Image` . It will scale the image to FIT the view but there can be white bands OR you can use `Aspect="AspectFill"` . It will scale the image to fill the entire view but border image parts can get cut.

Answer (score 5):

if you need a `70*70` Image shown in `Grid` and need `ColumnSpan = 2` . I have tested in my local project with the following codes , it works. Have a look as follows:

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="GreenYellow">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Frame Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="1"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
           Padding="0"
           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           CornerRadius="100"
           IsClippedToBounds="True"
           HeightRequest="70"
           WidthRequest="70"
           BackgroundColor="SaddleBrown">
        <Image Source="icon.png"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

Effect :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Corner radius should be half of your picture height if you want circled image. For example,  CornerRadius="35" IsClippedToBounds="True" HeightRequest="70".